# Program adds Header to CSV file each time ran

Tags: java, header, export-to-csv

I wrote this code over a year ago for a programming class with Java. It is a basic food log console application that creates a CSV file and can append input from the user once created. I ran into an issue that I was never able to resolve. I haven't done much with programming in a while, but I'm curious about the solution. The issue is that each time the program runs, it inserts another header in the CSV . I only want it to insert upon the initial creation, and if the file already exists, to skip.

My initial thought was an else if (file.exists() == true) { remaining code block }; in the 'try' block, but it doesn't write the header at all.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FoodLogWriter {

private static final String COMMA_DELIMITER = ",";
private static final String NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR = "\n";
private static final String FILE_HEADER = "Date,Food Time,Food Item,Calories,Carbohydrates,Sugar,Protein,Fiber,Total Fat";
private static Scanner kb;

public static void writeFoodLog(String fileName, File file) throws IOException {

    List<FoodLog> list = new ArrayList<FoodLog>();
    FoodLogApp app = new FoodLogApp();

    kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    String Dinput;
    String FTinput;
    String FIinput;
    double CALinput;
    double CARBinput;
    double Sinput;
    double Pinput;
    double TFinput;
    double Finput;

    int i = 0;

    while (i < 1000) {

        System.out.print("Enter the date: ");
        Dinput = kb.next();

        System.out.print("Enter the food time: ");
        FTinput = kb.next();

        System.out.print("Enter the food item: ");
        FIinput = kb.next();

        System.out.print("Enter the calories: ");
        CALinput = kb.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter the carbohydrates: ");
        CARBinput = kb.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter the sugar: ");
        Sinput = kb.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter the protein: ");
        Pinput = kb.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter the fiber: ");
        Finput = kb.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter the total fat: ");
        TFinput = kb.nextDouble();

        list.add(app.createFoodLog(Dinput, FTinput, FIinput, CALinput, CARBinput, Sinput, Pinput, Finput, TFinput));

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Do you have another item to input? ");
        String response = kb.next();
        System.out.println("");

        if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {

            app.printFoodLog(list);
            break;

        } else {
            i++;
        }

        kb.nextLine();

    }

    FileWriter fileWriter = null;

    try {

        fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName, true);

        if (file.exists() == false) {
            fileWriter.write(FILE_HEADER.toString());
        }
        fileWriter.append(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);

        for (FoodLog FL : list) {
            fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(FL.getDate()));
            fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
            fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(FL.getFoodTime()));
            fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
            fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(FL.getFoodItem()));
            fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
            fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(FL.getCalories()));
            fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
            fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(FL.getCarbohydrates()));
            fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
            fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(FL.getSugar()));
            fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
            fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(FL.getProtein()));
            fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
            fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(FL.getFiber()));
            fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
            fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(FL.getTotalFat()));
            fileWriter.append(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);
        }

        System.out.println("CSV file was created successfully.");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error in FoodLogWriter.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        try {
            fileWriter.flush();
            fileWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error while flushing/closing file writer.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Use the debugger to step through the code and see what it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the remaining classes:

```
public class FoodLog {

private String Date;
private String FoodTime;
private String FoodItem;
private double Calories;
private double Carbohydrates;
private double Sugar;
private double Fiber;
private double Protein;
private double TotalFat;

public FoodLog(String Date, String FoodTime, String FoodItem, double Calories, double Carbohydrates, double Sugar,
        double Fiber, double Protein, double TotalFat) {

    // super();
    this.Date = Date;
    this.FoodTime = FoodTime;
    this.FoodItem = FoodItem;
    this.Calories = Calories;
    this.Carbohydrates = Carbohydrates;
    this.Sugar = Sugar;
    this.Fiber = Fiber;
    this.Protein = Protein;
    this.TotalFat = TotalFat;

}

public String getDate() {
    return Date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    Date = date;
}

public String getFoodTime() {
    return FoodTime;
}

public void setFoodTime(String foodTime) {
    FoodTime = foodTime;
}

public String getFoodItem() {
    return FoodItem;
}

public void setFoodItem(String foodItem) {
    FoodItem = foodItem;
}

public double getCalories() {
    return Calories;
}

public void setCalories(double calories) {
    Calories = calories;
}

public double getCarbohydrates() {
    return Carbohydrates;
}

public void setCarbohydrates(double carbohydrates) {
    Carbohydrates = carbohydrates;
}

public double getSugar() {
    return Sugar;
}

public void setSugar(double sugar) {
    Sugar = sugar;
}

public double getFiber() {
    return Fiber;
}

public void setFiber(double fiber) {
    Fiber = fiber;
}

public double getProtein() {
    return Protein;
}

public void setProtein(double protein) {
    Protein = protein;
}

public double getTotalFat() {
    return TotalFat;
}

public void setTotalFat(double totalFat) {
    TotalFat = totalFat;
}

public String toString() {
    return "FoodLog [Date = " + Date + ", Food Time = " + FoodTime + ", Food Item = " + FoodItem + ", Calories = "
            + Calories + ", Carbohydrates = " + Carbohydrates + ", Sugar = " + Sugar + ", Fiber = " + Fiber
            + ", Protein = " + Protein + ", Total Fat = " + TotalFat + "]";

}
```

}

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class FoodLogApp {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File file = new File("FoodLog.csv");
    String fileName = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/FoodLog.csv";
    FoodLogWriter.writeFoodLog(fileName, file);

}

public FoodLog createFoodLog(String Date, String FoodTime, String FoodItem, double Calories, double Carbohydrates,
        double Sugar, double Fiber, double Protein, double TotalFat) {

    return new FoodLog(Date, FoodTime, FoodItem, Calories, Carbohydrates, Sugar, Fiber, Protein, TotalFat);
}

public void printFoodLog(List<FoodLog> list) {

    for (FoodLog FL : list) {

        System.out.println("===========================================");
        System.out.println("Food Time : " + FL.getFoodTime());
        System.out.println("Food Item : " + FL.getFoodItem());
        System.out.println("Calories : " + FL.getCalories());
        System.out.println("Carbohydrates : " + FL.getCarbohydrates());
        System.out.println("Sugar : " + FL.getSugar());
        System.out.println("Protein : " + FL.getProtein());
        System.out.println("Fiber : " + FL.getFiber());
        System.out.println("Total Fat : " + FL.getTotalFat());
        System.out.println("===========================================");
        System.out.println("");         
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem stems from the way you try to determine whether the actual file exists or not, before deciding on which actions to take (write the header or not).

In FoodLogApp#main, you create a new file each time it gets run (FoodLog.csv) which you then pass FoodLogWriter#writeFoodLog. This file gets created as an instance variable at this point and exists in the memory of the JVM, checking on whether this exists is not is what is causing your issues (since at that point this would always return true).

I would suggest that you try implementing a proper way of checking whether a file has been persisted in any way. That is, you need to perform an I/O action to determine whether a file exists in your give filepath (fileName variable).

Your easiest way to do so would be to use java .nio package. Start by creating a Path object using Paths.get("file_path"). Then use Files.exists() to check whether an actual file exists at the given path.

I suppose this would solve your problem. Waiting to hear whether it worked or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here :

```
File file = new File("FoodLog.csv");
String fileName = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/FoodLog.csv";
```

Variable **file** depends of where you are executing the java program (that is because you are using a relative path instead of a absolute path), **fileName** not. So if you are executing in /home/youruser/, it's going to work, but if you are executing in another folder as for example /home/youruser/project/, **file** is going to be "/home/youruser/project/FoodLog.csv".

I recommend you to change only the order and use the same variable:

```
String fileName = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/FoodLog.csv";
File file = new File(fileName);
```